# Regex when pattern involves dollar sign ($)

Tags: java, regex

I'm running into a bit of an issue when it comes to matching sub-patterns that involve the dollar sign. For example, consider the following chunk of text:

```
(en $) foo
oof ($).
ofo (env. 80 $US)
```

I'm using the following regex :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "\\([\\p{InARABIC}\\s]+\\)|\\([\\p{InBasic_Latin}\\s?\\$]+\\)|\\)([\\p{InARABIC}\\s]+)\\(",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public String replace(String text) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        String replacement = m.replaceAll(match -> {
            if (m.group(1) == null) {
                return m.group();
            } else {
                return "(" + match.group(1) + ")";
            }
        });
        return replacement;
    }
```

but can't match text containing `$`

Comment: Are you using `find()` or `matches()`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that i'm using matcher

Comment: Are you using `matches` or `find`? `matches` won't work as your string doesn't match the regex. Also, in case you are rightly using `find` even then your third sample won't give you anything as it contains a `.` inside it which is not there in your regex

Comment: You have not added `$` to all your alternatives. They do not match dots either as Pushpesh has already mentioned.

Comment: it matches the second no ? ```|\\([\\p{InBasic_Latin}\\s?\\$]+\\)|```

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html *"The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash"*.

Comment: _"Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly reduces readability."_

Answer (score 2):

This code is similar to `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`. Problem is that `$` isn't only special in *regex* argument, but also in *replacement* where it can be used as reference to match from groups like `$x` (where `x` is group ID) or `${groupName}` if your regex has `(?<groupName>subregex)`.

This allows us to write code like

```
String doubled = "abc".replaceAll(".", "$0$0");
System.out.println(doubled); //prints: aabbcc
```

which will replace each character with its two copies since each character will be matched by `.` and placed in group 0, so `$0$0` represents two repetitions of that matched character.

But in your case you have `$` in your `text`, so when it is matched you are replacing it with itself, so you are using in replacement `$` *without any information about group ID* (or group name) which results in `IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference`.

Solution is to **escape that `$` in *replacement* part**. You can do it manually, with `\`, but it is better to use method designed for that purpose [`Matcher#quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) (in case regex will evolve and you will need to escape more things, this method should evolve along with regex engine which should save you some trouble later)

So try changing your code to

```
public String replace(String text) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        String replacement = m.replaceAll(match -> {
            if (m.group(1) == null) {
                return Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group());
                //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            } else {
                return Matcher.quoteReplacement("(" + match.group(1) + ")");
                //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            }
        });
        return replacement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I keep this pattern :  ```Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "\\([\\p{InARABIC}\\s]+\\)|\\([\\p{InBasic_Latin}\\s?\\$]+\\)|\\)([\\p{InARABIC}\\s]+)\\(",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);``` should be this way

Comment: You are welcome. BTW I am not sure why you are using `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag. Usually it is used when regex contains explicit characters like `a` `b` and you want them to represent also `A` and `B`, but character classes like `\w` and I am assuming `\p{InBasic_Latin}` should by default contain all forms (upper and lower) of any character. Does this not apply to `\p{InARABIC}`, or did you add that flag just to be safe?

Comment: I kept that flag just to be safe as you mentioned.

Comment: quoteReplacement prevents you from using capture groups in the replacement regex at all.

Comment: @Alkanshel True, but that is kind of whole point of using `quoteReplacement` - to escape all metacharacters in *replacement* part which includes `$`. IMO if handled text contains any `$` or ``\`` those metacharacters should be escaped. For instance if it contains `random value is: a$ab$0cd` my guess is that `$0` *should* be "escaped" instead of referring to whole match. BUT If OP wants to refer to capturing groups in replacement he can still do it "outside" of `quoteReplacement` result, like `return "$0 " +Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group());`